# Ionic, PHP, MySQL and JSONP with Angular

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, .htaccess

I was trying to get the parameter from my php page to android app,

here the code on **js.php**

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$rest=$_GET['rest'];

if ($rest=="query"){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray['posts'] = $post;
        $post[] = str_replace('"', "'", $row);
    }
    $json = json_encode($emparray);

echo isset($_GET['callback'])
    ? "{$_GET['callback']}($json)"
    : $json;
}
?>
```

and I'm using **.htaccess** on my server

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule    ^rest/([A-Za-z]+)/?$    js.php?rest=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and last, my js on ionic **www\js\app.js**

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ionic']);


App.service("Robo", ["$http", "$log", Robo])
App.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", "Robo", "$log", AppCtrl]);


function AppCtrl($scope, Robo, $log){
    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.refresh = function(){
        Robo.getBlogs($scope);
    }
} 
   function Robo($http, $log) {
        this.getBlogs = function($scope){
                $http.jsonp("http://www.domain.com/rest/query?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
                    .success(function(result){
                        $scope.posts = result.posts;
                        $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                    });
        }
    }
```

on index.html

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="App">
<ion-content>
                <ion-refresher on-refresh="refresh()"></ion-refresher>
                <div data-ng-show="!posts.length">
                    <br><br>
                    <center>
                        <h1>Pull to Refresh</h1>
                    </center>
                </div>
.
.
.
```

I'm stuck here with no data on array $scope.posts, so when I pull the refresh, the loading never end. please kindly help and suggest me to solve this issue

Comment: Look what is in the Network pane of Developer Tools - request status and response body are important to check where the problem is coming from.

Comment: `content-type: application/json` — JSONP isn't JSON, the correct content-type is `application/javascript`

Comment: I already change to app;ication/javascript but still the post can't show on my android app

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing any kind of proper error handling. [`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) can very well be `FALSE`.

Your biggest problem seems to be that you do not understand the lifetime of a variable. A typical variable is declared, then instantiated, then used in some way and finally deleted. PHP is not strongly-typed, so a variable is usually declared and instantiated at the same time. PHP also will delete the variable for you once it goes out of scope.

Now let's take a look at your code. I've added comments with what each variable contains after each line:

```
/* $emparray = NULL */
$emparray = array();
/* $emparray = Array() */
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    /* $post = NULL
     * $emparray = Array() (1st time) or...
     * $emparray = Array( "posts" => NULL )
     * $row = Array( content )
     */
    $emparray['posts'] = $post;
    /* $post = NULL
     * $emparray = Array( "posts" => NULL )
     * $row = Array( content )
     */
    $post[] = str_replace('"', "'", $row);
    /* $post = Array( 0 => content_with_quotes_replaced )
     * $emparray = Array( "posts" => NULL )
     * $row = Array( content )
     */
}
/* $emparray = Array( "posts" => NULL */
$json = json_encode($emparray);
```

That was not very useful, was it? You are assigning a value to `$post`, then let it go out of scope. You are also replacing the key "posts" in $emparray with the content of the `$post` variable every time you go through the loop. Since the `$post` variable is not defined, it's value will always be NULL at that point.

Another problem your code has, is that if the query does not return any result, the loop will not be run, and thus you'll end up with an array without the "posts" key in it completely.

An more obscure problem is that by replacing double quotes with single quotes in `$row`, you might end up with something that does not make sense. You probably want to escape your quotes instead.

---

So, how do you improve this? First choose a better name for `$emparray`. It does not convey what this variable is about. Add the posts-key to that array, with an empty array as value. Perform any actions you need to perform on `$row` and put the result in it's own variable. Then add it to the resulting array with the syntax you already used (`$variable['posts'][] = ...`). Finally turn that into your string in json format.

Comment: Hi Sumurai8, with my coding as I mention above, if I use browser to open the php page, it was show the data. but the problem was, I use the $http.jsonp on my angular controller but I can't get the data on variable $scope.posts = result.posts;